# How do I enable my back button only when a link is clicked in my UIWebView? (Code won't execute)

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uiwebview, back

I'm trying to make it so that the back button will only be enabled when the user presses a link and/or if canGoBack = TRUE. I tried using an if statement in the body but that didn't work. I then tried using what I could find online and it still didn't work. My code is below. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:    (NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:      (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        NSString *url = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
        NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSURLRequest *nsrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
        [webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
        backButton.enabled = TRUE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Define what "it still didn't work" means.

Comment: Why have you got all that stuff in shouldStartLoadWithRequest? You don't need to load stuff yourself, that method is just for asking permission if the page should be loaded or not. You're perhaps messing up the web view's navigation stack doing that and I wouldn't be surprised if as a consequence canGoBack will never be YES.

Comment: I have the buttons initialized as backButton.enabled = FALSE and same for forward. They stay disabled even when I click on a link in my webview.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code for shouldStartLoadWithRequest and confirmed the code in the if statement is executing? As mentioned above, you should also chop out all that NSURLRequest stuff unless there is some  advanced use case and you know what you are doing.

Comment: If you mean in the function above, nothing is executing. I just tried it without an if statement and it still won't execute the change in backButton.enabled. The  page loads regardless.

Comment: Then your question should actually not be why is my back button not working, but why isn't shouldStartLoadWithRequest not being invoked (you said nothing is executing, therefore that method can't be being called if nothing at all within it is being executed). If thats the case then start a new question and show more of you code, especially how you are initially creating and loading the web view. But first *make sure you have set the web view delegate*. If you didn't, that is why its not being called.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "set the web view delegate?" I initialized web view as usual programmatically. Everything else works with my view except for this. I'm self-learning as I'm new to objective-c so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Added as an answer. Read about delegates in Objective-C, you can't get far not knowing about them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldStartLoadWithRequest() won't get called if you haven't set the web view's delegate.

In order to use UIWebView its typically set as an outlet property of a view controller, so you should have something like this:

```
IBOutlet  UIWebView*    webView;
```

The webView has a delegate property which needs setting to your view controller, you can set delegates in a storyboard, but its more explicit to set it in code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
```

99% of the time you just set delegates, but UIWebView's delegate is funny in that it needs setting to nil when finished with. So add this:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self.webView stopLoading];
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
```

Comment: I added an update about setting it to nil. By the way UIWebView is now deprecated/old. If you're just working with iOS8 its better to use its replacement, I forget what its called but should be easy to find by googling.

Answer (score -1):

`UIWebView` and `WKWebView` both have a `canGoBack` and `canGoForward` property on them. You can use KVO to see when these are enabled, and enable/disable your back and forward buttons accordingly.

http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/